# What's the difference between the two `SetState()` usages?

Tags: flutter, dart, state

Just wondering if there is any difference between:

```dart
      // == Add all picked idoes to the mix table
      setState(() {
        Future.forEach(result, (asset) async {
          final video = await MixTableVideo.create(original: asset);
          videos.add(video);
        });
      });
```

and:

```dart
      // == Add all picked idoes to the mix table

      Future.forEach(result, (asset) async {
          final video = await MixTableVideo.create(original: asset);
          videos.add(video);
        });

      setState(() {});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did this which fires a UI update at each video addition:

```dart
      // == Add all picked videos to the mix table
      Future.forEach(result, (asset) async {
        final video = await MixTableVideo.create(original: asset);
        setState(() {
          videos.add(video);
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Before we can use state, we need to declare a default set of values for the initial state. This can be done by either creating a state object in the constructor or directly within the class.